# Any faster solution other than this bruteforce approach

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been submitting programs to this problem at ACM. [Problem ID=1922](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1922) but my solution keeps getting **Time Limit Exceeded** on test 3.

My idea is to use brute-force but with some branches-cutting-off. The below is my Java code, any faster solutions or improvements would be appreciated... I guess this isn't difficult at all because the difficulty is only 195, but I just can't get it accepted.

Finally got it accepted. The algorithm is to first sort the heroes, and start with the smallest-wish first. Just O(n)..

My Java code is so far the fastest [Solution Rank](http://acm.timus.ru/rating.aspx?space=1&num=1922&lang=java)

Many thanks!

```
public class testtest
{
    static boolean[] used;
    // length of heros
    static int ulen;
    // list of heros
    static Wish[] w;
    // number of possible teams
    static int count = 0;
    // and output
    static StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    // add the team

    // check if it is a valid team
    static boolean check(int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ulen; i ++)
        {
            if (!used[i])
            {
                            // adding another hero makes it reliable, so invalid
                if (w[i].wish <= len + 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    // search the teams, team size = total, current pick = len, start from root + 1
    static void search(int root, int total, int len)
    {
        if (len >= total) // finish picking len heros
        {
            if (check(total))  // valid
            {
                print(total);  // add to output
            }
            return;
        }
        for (int i = root + 1; i < ulen; i ++)
        {
            if (w[i].wish > len + ulen - i)
            {
                return; // no enough heros left, so return
            }
            else
            if (w[i].wish <= total)  // valid hero for this team
            {
                used[i] = true;
                search(i, total, len + 1);  // search next hero
                used[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader rr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ulen = Integer.parseInt(rr.readLine());
        w = new Wish[ulen];
        for (int i = 0; i < ulen; i ++)
        {
            w[i] = new Wish(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(rr.readLine()));
        }
        Arrays.sort(w);
        used = new boolean[ulen];
        Arrays.fill(used, false);
        for (int i = 1; i <= ulen; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= ulen - i; j ++)
            {
                if (w[j].wish <= i) // this hero is valid
                {
                    used[j] = true;
                    search(j, i, 1);
                    used[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at combinatorics.

Comment: I think the algorithm is still based on search because the entire list needs to be printed, not just the total number of answers.

Comment: Nothing to do with the algorithm, but changing your `+` inside `StringBuffer.append` calls will certainly shave-off some time.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I don't think the effect will be very large though.

Comment: How long does your code take to run?

Comment: @JanDvorak Probably not, but every little bit helps ;)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just generate all of the combinations for each hero, then iterate through them ignoring all of the groupings that are not reliable or not effective.

Comment: the maximum allowed time is 1 second on the server.

Comment: Yes. that is what my code does.. It also has some cut-offs.

Comment: What I'm saying is if you are looking at a hero that requires a *minimum* team size of 3, you only need all the 3-combinations of your set of heroes. And you can immediately discard any of those elements if they have > 3. You also can discard any elements with minimum size `x` where `x` is greater than the number of heroes in the world.

Comment: The problem with your code is you didn't document it. Which is why I imagine no one has answered your question, they don't want to take the time to figure out what you are doing.

Comment: @DoctorLai I worked up a solution that I am willing to post, I don't know if it will pass the online judge as I wrote it in Ruby not knowing that the judge only accepts specific languages. Would you be interested in me doing this ?

Comment: try  Christopher Schultz's idea, changing '+' in str.append, it still is TL3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, my results (of Java) is the fastest.
http://acm.timus.ru/rating.aspx?space=1&num=1922&lang=java

The fact that I didn't make full use before is that I have sorted list of heroes according to their wishes.

Therefore, the main loop just needs to be changed to O(n) instead of O(n^2)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ulen; i ++)
{
    if (w[0].wish <= i)
    {
        used[0] = true;
        search(0, i, 1);
        used[0] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have that executes for the sample test in ~0.00013 seconds (on my CPU):

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Hero.java
 *
 * This program solves the Super Hero problem put forth by Timus Online Judge  
 * http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1922
 *
 * @author  Hunter McMillen
 * @version 1.0 12/29/2012
 */
public class Hero {
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private static List<Integer>                indices  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static boolean[]                    used;

    /**
     * Entry point into the application
     *
     * @args command line arguments
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int numHeroes, wish;
    List<Integer> heroes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<List<Integer>> groups;

    // read number of heroes 
    numHeroes = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    // read 'numHeroes' wishes from stdin
    // filter out heroes that have a minimum required that exceeds
    // the number of heroes
    for(int i = 0; i < numHeroes; i++) {
        wish = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        if(wish <= numHeroes)
        heroes.add(wish);
    }

    // split into groups
    groups = reliableGroups(heroes);

    // output results
    System.out.println(groups.size());
    for(List<Integer> g : groups) {
        System.out.println(g.size() + " " + g.toString().replaceAll("[\\]\\[\\,]", ""));
    }
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether a group is effective, meaning that all wishes
     * for that group are met
     *
     * @group The group to evaluate for effectiveness
     */
    public static boolean isEffective(List<Integer> group)  {
    int maxWish = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int temp; 

    // find the maximum wish size of all members in group
    for(int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++) {
        if((temp = indexMap.get(group.get(i))) > maxWish)
        maxWish = temp;
    }

    // make sure that the maximum wish size is respected
    return group.size() >= maxWish;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if there exists some other superhero
     * that when added to this group makes another effective group
     *
     * @effectiveGroup The current grouping that is effective but might
     *                 not be reliable
     */ 
    public static boolean isReliable(List<Integer> effectiveGroup) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= indices.size(); i++) {
        if(!used[i]) {
        // add another hero to this group to see if it remains effective 
        effectiveGroup.add(i);

        // if it is still effective, then this group is not reliable
        if(isEffective(effectiveGroup))
            return false;

        // remove the hero that was temporarily added
        effectiveGroup.remove(effectiveGroup.size()-1);
        }
    }

    // true if adding any unused member to this group made it ineffective
    return true;
    }

    /**
     * Separates the List<Integer> of heroes into reliable groups
     *
     * @heroes The List of heroes
     */
    public static List<List<Integer>> reliableGroups(List<Integer> heroes) {
    List<List<Integer>> groups = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    boolean       effective    = true;
    int h, current;

    // create HashMap with mapping between hero wish values and their index
    for(int i = 1; i <= heroes.size(); i++) {
        indices.add(i);
        indexMap.put(i, heroes.get(i-1));
    }

    // create an array to track which heroes have been used
    used = new boolean[indices.size()+1];
    Arrays.fill(used, false);

    List<int[]>   combinations;
    List<Integer> tempList;
    for(int i = 1; i <= indices.size(); i++) { 
        h = indexMap.get(i);

        combinations = combination(heroes, h);

        // iterate over all combinations making sure the wish values are below
        // the threshold for this hero at map index `i`
        for(int[] aCombination : combinations) {
        for(int j = 0; j < aCombination.length; j++) {
            current = aCombination[j];
            used[current] = true;
            if(indexMap.get(current) > h) {
            effective = false;
            break;
            }
        }

        // create a List from the integer[] combination
        tempList = asList(aCombination);

        // if the group makeup is reliable, save it
        if(effective && !groups.contains(tempList) && isReliable(tempList))
            groups.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(tempList));

        // reset flags
        effective = true;
        Arrays.fill(used, false);
        }
    }

    return groups;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that returns a List<Integer> given  
     * an array of primitive ints
     *
     * @array The array to convert to a List<Integer>
     */
    public static List<Integer> asList(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> boxed = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        boxed.add(array[i]);
    }

    return boxed;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the intial r combination in ascending order
     * i.e [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., r]
     *
     * @r The size of the intial combination
     */ 
    public static int[] initialCombination(int r) {
    int[] indices = new int[r];

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        indices[i] = i+1;

    return indices;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the next combination given an array of indices
     * 
     * @indicesIn The array of indices
     * @n         The size of this combination
     */
    public static int[] nextCombination(int[] indicesIn, int n) {
    int[] indices = (int[])indicesIn.clone();
    int r = indices.length;

    // find the rightmost index that is not at its final highest value
    int i = 0;
    for (i = r - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (indices[i] != (i + n - r + 1)) {
        break;
        }
    }

    // return null if no more combinations exist
    if (i == -1)
        return null;

    // increment rightmost index
    indices[i]++;

    // reset all the indices to the right of indices[i]
    // to their smallest possible value.
    for (int j = i + 1; j < r; j++) {
        indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1;
    }

    return indices;
    }

    /**
     * Generates all r-combinations of the indices array
     * 
     * @heroes The array of heroes wishes
     * @r      The length of the combination to generate
     */
    public static List<int[]> combination(List<Integer> heroes, int r) {
    List<int[]> combinations = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] indices = initialCombination(r);

    while(indices != null) {
        combinations.add(indices);
        indices = nextCombination(indices, heroes.size());
    }

    return combinations;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks... the sample test is simple, so it shouldn't take long.. the problem description states that the input size of heroes can take up to 1000...  Is it possible for you to write in C/C++ or, C#, java? You code much depends on some inbuilt statements/functions of ruby, such as combination.

Comment: @DoctorLai Yeah, I can work at converting it. I might not have time today, but I will try.

Comment: @DoctorLai I am going to try to beat yours :)

Comment: @DoctorLai I keep getting WA on test 2 but I have no idea why? My output matches what was posted on the board. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried the tests here? http://acm.timus.ru/forum/thread.aspx?id=29056&upd=634923013790049302

Comment: @DoctorLai Yes, I get the same output as those tests on my local machine, but still get WA

Comment: could you post your java code so I can have a look.... I am not familiar with Ruby...

Comment: try the input '5 1 1 1 1 1', the output should be '5 1 2 3 4 5', but your code produces '0'.

Comment: @DoctorLai Thanks, I didnt really consider this case. I need to re-think how I evaluate groups.